# Handling Cross-Database Operations in Microservices with Azure SQL and .NET 7

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, microservices, .net-7.0

I'm currently working on a project involving multiple micro services developed using .NET 7 and a database hosted on Azure SQL (PaaS). While designing the architecture, I've encountered a couple of challenges that I would like some guidance on:

**1. Connecting to multiple databases using Entity Framework Core**

In some cases, a micro service needs to connect to two different databases hosted on Azure SQL via Entity Framework Core. Essentially, there might be scenarios where a micro service has to interact with two different tables located in separate databases on the same Azure SQL server. I'm looking for advice on the best approach to handle this situation without compromising on performance and maintainability.

**2. Referring to tables in different databases in Azure SQL from stored procedures**

I'm also seeking guidance on how to implement a solution at the stored procedure level that involves referencing tables located in distinct databases on Azure SQL. It's crucial to maintain data integrity and ensure efficient execution when dealing with such cross-database operations.

While researching, I came across the option of using cross-database queries (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-query-getting-started-vertical?view=azuresql). However, my concern is that this feature is currently in preview stage. I'm hesitant to implement it at a production level without more confidence in its stability and performance.

I would greatly appreciate any insights, best practices, or alternative approaches that the community can provide. If there are any real-world examples or experiences related to similar scenarios, those would be invaluable in making an informed decision for our architecture.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance

Answer (score 1):

it is worse than you think. The "standard" approach for a microservice is to be independent, so it has its OWN database and interacts with that (only). Ther are edge cases (like a library or product catalog that gets updated irregularly), but otherwise - that is it. The idea, after all, is that a microservice can be maintained independently of the other microservices.

And the result is an atrocious resource usage and performance.

In this case your way to deal with data from other microservices is to ASK THEM - the services, not the database. This does NOT involve stored procedures - after all, a SP on YOUR microservice is a maintenance burden for whoever owns the table. You sould ask a method on the microservice that owns the table to provide you with the data.

So, people go into Silos of "vaguel" microservices that share a common database. Performance and ressouce usage is way less atrocious - but you have to live with the performance.

If the data lives in one database - then seriously, stop assuming it is a microservice - it is a service on top of a SHARED database, so i.e. your EF Core library should be a shared resource kept current with the database that everyone using it (and using .NET) can use.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Design Patterns.
For ex, I was working on a project where the data was supposed to saved according to the country. There were multiple countries where our app was working and each country had its own database.
The entry point for us was to show a pop up to the user on which country he was from and the save all the data in the country database.
We had a `Factory Design Pattern` to resolve the databases according to the country.

There was one common database to store just user information(Login, Logout and Session id's), this we handled with Attributes at controller level to just log/save the user info in one common table mentioning the DBO.

Comment: Thanks @Ajay Managaon for your response. In my case we have certain common data in a central database (for example user data and master data) and one more database hosted per region. Now in certain cases I need to fetch data from both Central database and the region specific database. Can you please help me to know what is the design pattern you have used in your implementation. Any specific details in context to the implementation will help me a lot.

Comment: If its single server and different database then you can fetch it mentioning the database directly at entity framework level/ADO level. At the database side, SQL server allows you join and operate on multiple tables form database too, you can do it from stored procedures as well. its not with Design patterns.

Comment: In my case the databases are hosted on Azure SQL. Performing joins across two different databases is only possible via cross database queries which is again in Preview stage now and not allowed to be used in PRODUCTION.

Comment: Then you need to work on Database Design again, Only keep common information related to user in one database, rest all data you push it to individual database, resolve the database as per the region and push it to that database only. As joins across multiple database on different server is costly performance wise.

Comment: Another solution would be NoSQL like Cosmos DB or DynamoDB, as headache of joining would not be there. Save all the data in a collection. Just resolve the database.